# CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected;

Tags: bluetooth

I am getting this error when I want to use bluetooth usb on my device. How can I use it actively
`sudo dmesg | grep Bluetooth`

```
Core ver 2.22
[    2.063507] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.063509] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.063511] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.063514] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.088133] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Setting up dongle with HCI ver=9 rev=3120
[    2.088137] Bluetooth: hci0: LMP ver=9 subver=22bb; manufacturer=10
[    2.088139] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[    2.444640] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    2.444643] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    2.444646] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    7.103183] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Couldn't suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[    7.103220] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Delete Stored Link Key command is advertised, but not supported.
[    7.103220] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Read Default Erroneous Data Reporting command is advertised, but not supported.
[    7.103221] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Set Event Filter command not supported.
[    9.150539] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[  142.655234] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Setting up dongle with HCI ver=9 rev=3120
[  142.655236] Bluetooth: hci0: LMP ver=9 subver=22bb; manufacturer=10
[  142.655237] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[  147.764133] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Couldn't suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[  147.764156] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Delete Stored Link Key command is advertised, but not supported.
[  147.764157] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Read Default Erroneous Data Reporting command is advertised, but not supported.
[  147.764158] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Set Event Filter command not supported.
```